# Confusion concerning OleDbCommand

Tags: c#

I know that to instantiate a new OLEDbCommand object you do this:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
```

However, I am confused as to what this line of code is doing:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = aConnection.CreateCommand();
```

I know that aConnection is an OleDbConnection object which was instantiated earlier in the code.

From the MSDN Library I know that CreateCommand() is an OdbcCommand object associated with the OdbcConnection.  However, the Library doesn't really go any further to explain its purpose.

Even though I know what the individual components are, I am unsure of what is happening here.  Is cmd an OleDbCommand object that is being instantiated in order to be able to use SQL commands?  I infer this because further on in the code there is the following:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Team where typeOfSport = '" + typeOfSport + "'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just creating a command from the connection object.  The command will be associated with the connection it was created from.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
```

is the same as

```
OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()
```

Comment: "Its no different than creating the command with the new statement and setting connection property to the connection object."  OK.  so in essence it's a shortcut.  I didn't know you could do that.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.createcommand.aspx) `aConnection.CreateCommand()`:

> Creates and returns an OleDbCommand object associated with the
>   OleDbConnection.

This basically is a convenience method which already sets up the respective connection on the command without setting up the `CommandText` - thus could be used as a utility method whenever you need a `OleDbCommand` object without supplying the `CommandText` directly but later on...

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie you are welcome :-) please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted answers that are of help (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Done.  For some reason the system makes me wait 6 minutes before it allows me to upvote/mark accepted answers.  I guess it's to let tempers cool down if a flame war develops.